# Best coordinate system for Projectile motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, coordinate-systems

What is the best coordinate system for 
describing the projectile motion?
Rectangular coordinate system or n-t(normal 
and tangential) coordinate system.

Comment: Personally i find the latter better.

Comment: This seems *primarily opinion-based* as both descriptions are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a particle in a gravitational field treated as a constant? Surely Newton's equations of motion in the fixed rectangular frame:

$$\ddot{x}=0$$
$$\ddot{y}=-g$$

are as simple as it can get!

Comment: By constant particle do you mean that tnis system is not best for missiles's motion lets say an example.

Comment: @SohailAhmed I mean that the gravitational field is treated as a constant $g$, as opposed to a gravitational field which might go like $\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$. The second case is a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If the range is not too large, you can approximate the acceleration (due to gravity) vector to have the same direction over the trajectory of the projectile. It will probably be a good idea to use earth fixed 2D cartesian coordinates in this case, one axis horizontal and the other vertical to the Earth's surface. The acceleration acts only along the vertical direction. The motion projected onto the horizontal direction becomes free of acceleration.